# CSS - on hover image half slide up

Tags: css, image, hover, slideup

**Want same result as code below but instead of background want hover on image**

**On image hover want to slide up with content**

**The code**

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #ff0;
}
.hid-box {
  top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  background: #428bca;
  height: 100%;
}

.box:hover > .hid-box{
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <!-- <img src="pic1.png"> -->
    <div class="hid-box">
      <h1>CSS3 slide up</h1>
      <p>This is a quick demo of slide-up effect using CSS animation when hover the box. No JS required!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Tried With image tag but it is not working, the image don't has fix size `<div class="box">` will not work.**

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #ff0;
}

.hid-box {
  top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  background: #428bca;
  height: 100%;
}

.box:hover>.hid-box {
  top: 80px;
}

.box img {
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/124x124/000/fff.png&text=pic1">
    <div class="hid-box">
      <h1>CSS3 slide up</h1>
      <p>This is a quick demo of slide-up effect using CSS animation when hover the box. No JS required!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Finally achived wanted result**

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .image {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
  }
  
  .container:hover .overlay {
    height: 50%;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/120x120/000/fff.png&text=120x120" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please could you check your question because nothing is showing between the The code and Want same result … so we don’t know what is being aimed for.

Comment: can you explain what you want to achieve because there is no image where you want to hover?

Comment: Don't want to be rude, but it looks to me you haven't even tried. If the image should fit the box, you may use the `background` property of the box to show the image. If you want to use the `img` tag, use a class like the one of the box, make it a block level element using the display property and use :hover in the same way.

Comment: @aman, that is my question instead of  ``<div class="box">``. I am want to place ``<img>``, I didn't post the code with ``<img>`` because I am not getting proper result.

Comment: @omkar please post your code so can get your point and issue

Comment: you could try uncomment the img, use absolute position and see if that works fine https://jsfiddle.net/eo89acL5/ ??

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, this is what I want but the image size is not fix so it will not work for me. ``<img>`` must be act like ``<div class="box">`` @christo @Aman @G-Cyrillus, Please check my edited Question.

Comment: okay, you need to find out how position:absolute and relative can work together to achieve what you want, you can swap positions of text and image to keep image in the flow and size your box ;) this is an hint ;)

Comment: christo, Aman, G-Cyrillus, Please check Question. Finally got the wanted result but don't know how it worked :P. Mostly, I work on PHP, I am not very good at this design stuff. Please share useful link from where I can learn CSS and CSS animations. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**Do you need to size the box to the image's size ?**

if yes, the box needs to shrink on it and img to remain in the flow, then the text has to be removed from the flow via position:absolute.

make the box a relative box, so coordonates for absolute child will use the box for reference....

See the comments inside CSS to find out the purpose of chosen rules ;)

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0
}

.box {
/* size the box to the image's size */
  width:max-content;
  height:max-content;
  
  /* hide overflowing text box */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* make it the reference for absolute positionned children */
  position:relative;
  
  /* your style */
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #ff0;
}

.hid-box {
  position: absolute;/* take it off the flow, image is doing the sizing */
  bottom:0;/* defaut coordonate expected */
  top:100%;/* pushed off sight */
  margin-top:auto; /* keep it as close as possible to bottom */
 
 /* size it to the box */
  width: 100%; 
  height:max-content;/* do not let it grow bigger than its content */
  max-height:100%;/* but also do not let it grow taller than its parent box */
  overflow:auto;/*, let it scroll if contents overflows text box */
  
  /* your style */  
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  background: #428bca;
}

.box:hover>.hid-box {
  top:0;/* bring it back into view */
 
}

.box img {
  display:block;/* remove that white space below */
}

/* demo purpose */
body>div {float:left;margin:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/124x124/000/fff.png&text=pic1">
    <div class="hid-box">
      <h1>CSS3 slide up</h1>
      <p>This is a quick demo of slide-up effect using CSS animation when hover the box. No JS required!</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x224/000/fff.png&text=pic1">
    <div class="hid-box">
      <h1>CSS3 slide up</h1>
      <p>This is a quick demo of slide-up effect using CSS animation when hover the box. No JS required!</p>
    </div>
</div>
Then , use <b>figure</b> and <b>figcaption</b> tags instead <b>div</b>  ;)
<figure class="box">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x225/0f0/fff.png&text=figure_figcaption">
    <figcaption class="hid-box">
      <h1>CSS3 slide up</h1>
      <p>This is a quick demo of slide-up effect using CSS animation when hover the box. No JS required!</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```